# Excel formula: format DMS and convert to DD

Tags: excel, coordinates

I have a dataset (see table below) that I need to format to DMS and convert to DD. I need to use Excel formulas to try and accomplish this. I have tried to rearrange the following formula to fit my need but I am not having any luck.

> =--(INDEX({"+","+","-","-"},MATCH(LEFT(A1,1),{"E","N","W","S"},0))&MID(A1,3,FIND(" ",MID(A1,3,LEN(A1))))+MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",2))+1,2)/60+MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",3))+1,99)/3600)

Example Data:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have office 365?

Answer (score 0):

If your DMS entries are all in the format you show, then you can use the following formula for the conversion

***Office 365***

***DD LONG***

```
=LET(d,LEFT(A2,3),
m,MID(A2,4,2),
s,MID(A2,6,LEN(A2)-6),
sgn,IF(RIGHT(A2)="E",1,-1),
(d+m/60+s/3600)*sgn)
```

***DD LAT***

```
=LET(d,LEFT(B2,2),
m,MID(B2,3,2),
s,MID(B2,5,LEN(B2)-5),
sgn,IF(RIGHT(B2)="N",1,-1),
(d+m/60+s/3600)*sgn)
```

***Earlier versions of Excel***

***DD LONG***

```
=(LEFT(A2,3)+MID(A2,4,2)/60+MID(A2,6,LEN(A2)-6)/3600)*IF(RIGHT(A2)="E",1,-1)
```

***DD LAT***

```
=(LEFT(B2,2)+MID(B2,3,2)/60+MID(B2,5,LEN(B2)-5)/3600)*IF(RIGHT(B2)="N",1,-1)
```

[image]